# How to add Bing Map to Web Page?

Tags: dictionary, bing-maps

I tried to add bing map with place I marked on it, but it didn't work? I followed these steps:

1. Login to  http://www.bing.com/maps
2. Click on My Places
3. Create New List
4. Under that one I have marked place i want
5. Click on share button
6. Copy embed in a web page code and paste it on my page.

But I can't see place I marked, can someone please tell me what is the wrong thing I did?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed My Place's maps into a website. The My Places functionality is only available on the Bing Maps consumer site.

If you want to include a map on your website with data on it you have to use the Bing Maps development API's. Here are some resources to get you started:

- [Bing Maps V7 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx)
- [Bing Maps V7 Interactive SDK](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7)
- [Bing Maps Blog](http://blogs.bing.com/maps)
- [Bing Maps Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?category=bingmaps)